# CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER outputting the results when not needed

Tags: json, curl

I have the following code:

```
                            $ch = curl_init();

                            // set URL and other appropriate options
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 12); 
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                            //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

                            // grab URL and pass it to the browser
                            curl_exec($ch);

                            $res = curl_exec($ch);
                            var_dump($res);

                            // close cURL resource, and free up system resources
                            curl_close($ch);
                            echo "<br />\n";
                            echo "<br />\n";
                            $resArr = json_decode($res, 1); // decodes the json string to an array
                            echo $resArr['id'] // outputs the id from your json result
```

I do not want the JSON code to be displayed on the webpage, but rather to be stored in a variable so I can print it out when I want to.

I have read that CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER should work, however the results are still being displayed in JSON format. Could anyone advise of a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove or comment the `var_dump($res);` since this is print the data in `$res` and by removing it will not diplay the json data that you are receving from CURL. Hope this might help you.